Не работает бот телеграм
При попытке забанить пользователя у меня возникает ошибка polling error
const bot = new TelegramBot(TOKEN, {
   polling: {
      interval: 300,
      autoStart: true,
      params: {
         timeout: 10
      }
   }
});

bot.onText(/\/block_bots/, (msg) => {
   const chatId = msg.chat.id;
 bot.getChatAdministrators(chatId, (admin) => {
   console.log(admin)
 })
   bot.getChatMembersCount(chatId).then((count) => {
     // Получаем список участников группы или канала
     bot.getChatMembers(chatId).then((members) => {
       members.forEach((member) => {
         // Проверяем, является ли участник ботом
         if (member.user.is_bot) {
           bot.kickChatMember(chatId, member.user.id).catch((error) => {
             console.log(`Ошибка при блокировке бота: ${error}`);
           });
         }
       });
       bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Боты успешно заблокированы.');
      console.log(members)
     }).catch((error) => {
       console.log(`Ошибка при получении списка участников чата или канала: ${error}`);
     });
   }).catch((error) => {
     console.log(`Ошибка при получении количества участников чата или канала: ${error}`);
   });
 });

вот код
подскажите что я не учел

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1578587/telegram-bot-node-js-polling-error#comment2846789_1578587

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Telegram Bot Node JS polling error
